# Gradle copy task does not work

Tags: gradle

In my gradle/deployment.gradle file I have this:

```
basedir = devHomeDir.getAbsolutePath()
deploymentDir = new File(project, "deployment")
deploymentLibDir = new File(deploymentDir, 'project/lib')

task deployProjectJars(type: Copy) {
  from tasks.getByPath(':baseproject:project:assembleAll')
  into deploymentLibDir
  exclude '*-sources.jar'
}
```

When I run deployProjectJars as an output I get this: `:deployProjectJars NO-SOURCE` and nothing gets copied. So I added a task to gradle.build to copy those jars. So the question is - why my original approach does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You showed too few of your buildscripts to really answer the question thoroughly. But according to the little information you gave, I'd say that the assembleAll task has no outputs that could be copied, or only has outputs that match the `*-sources.jar` pattern.